# WASM does not export any methods

Tags: c++, cmake, webassembly, emscripten

I am using

- cmake v3.26.3
- emsdk/emcc/em++ v3.1.43 ([Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/))
- gcc/g++ v14.0.3 (Apple clang)

to build a WASM. After I build the WASM file, I inspect it with `wasm-objdump` and notice that there is no exported functions. I need to know what I am doing wrong. The project is just a toy project to troubleshoot the issue.

Here's `hpp/demo.hpp`.

```
#ifndef API_DEMO_H
#define API_DEMO_H

int add(int a, int b);

#endif
```

Here's `cpp/demo.cpp`.

```
#include "demo.hpp"

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Here's `cpp/CMakeLists.txt`.

```
include_directories(../hpp)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC *.cpp)
add_executable(api ${SRC})
set_target_properties(api PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "--no-entry")
set_target_properties(api PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "--no-entry")
```

And `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(api)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-std=c++17")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".wasm")

add_subdirectory(cpp)
```

To build the project I type in the following.

```
emcmake cmake -B build -S . 
cmake --build build -j 8
```

The file `build/cpp/api.wasm` is built without error. But then I issue the command `wasm-objdump -x build/cpp/api.wasm` and observe the following. As you can see, the `add` function is not exported. Any ideas?

```
api.wasm:   file format wasm 0x1

Section Details:

Type[4]:
 - type[0] () -> i32
 - type[1] () -> nil
 - type[2] (i32) -> nil
 - type[3] (i32) -> i32
Function[5]:
 - func[0] sig=1 <_initialize>
 - func[1] sig=0 <__errno_location>
 - func[2] sig=0 <stackSave>
 - func[3] sig=2 <stackRestore>
 - func[4] sig=3 <stackAlloc>
Table[1]:
 - table[0] type=funcref initial=2 max=2
Memory[1]:
 - memory[0] pages: initial=256 max=256
Global[1]:
 - global[0] i32 mutable=1 - init i32=66576
Export[7]:
 - memory[0] -> "memory"
 - func[0] <_initialize> -> "_initialize"
 - table[0] -> "__indirect_function_table"
 - func[1] <__errno_location> -> "__errno_location"
 - func[2] <stackSave> -> "stackSave"
 - func[3] <stackRestore> -> "stackRestore"
 - func[4] <stackAlloc> -> "stackAlloc"
Elem[1]:
 - segment[0] flags=0 table=0 count=1 - init i32=1
  - elem[1] = func[0] <_initialize>
Code[5]:
 - func[0] size=3 <_initialize>
 - func[1] size=5 <__errno_location>
 - func[2] size=4 <stackSave>
 - func[3] size=6 <stackRestore>
 - func[4] size=16 <stackAlloc>
```

The `add` function not being exported is verified on the HTML/JavaScript side too, showing `undefined`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const importObject = {
        env: {
          __linear_memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 }),
          __stack_pointer: new WebAssembly.Global({value:'i32', mutable:true,}, 0),
        }
      };

      WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
        fetch('build/cpp/api.wasm'),
        importObject
      ).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.instance.exports);
        console.log(result.instance.exports.add); // undefined
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a [FAQ on the emscripten website](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-do-functions-in-my-c-c-source-code-vanish-when-i-compile-to-javascript-and-or-i-get-no-functions-to-process)

Comment: why aren't you using `target_compile_options` and `target_link_options`? why are you doing `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-std=c++17")` if you also set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`? why are you doing `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -DNDEBUG")` instead of using the Release configuration?

Comment: @Botje `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS` sounds like a C thing? Jane, if EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS doesn't work for you, try https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html?highlight=keepalive#c.EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE. Let us know if either of those work.

Comment: `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE` is a macro for annotating functions (which need to have `external "C"` linkage to be usable), `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS` is a compiler flag. Both are mentioned in the FAQ I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe helps. I am using wasi instead of emscripten. Do not get me wrong, emscripten is good but for my project I need to call c/c++ functions in rust, process values and send it back to JS via wasm_bindgen. While C funtions works fine as they are, cpp functions needed some rework.

```
#define export __attribute__((visibility("default")))

extern "C" export int something()
    {
    return 0;
    }
```

In your case the `cpp/demo.cpp` file should look like this:

```
#include "demo.hpp"
#define export __attribute__((visibility("default")))

extern "C" export int add(int a, int b)
    {
    return a + b;
    }
```